# Add vimeo event listeners for multiple videos on same page

Tags: events, iframe, vimeo-api

I have multiple Vimeo videos iframes on the same page. So I want to add event listeners for all the iframes. But somehow it is not working for me.

here is the code which I add on document.ready.

```
 var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

var player;
//loop through all and add event
    for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        // when vimeo player is ready add other events
        player = $f(iframes[i]);

        player.addEvent('ready', function () {         

            player.addEvent('play', onPlay);
            player.addEvent('pause', onPause);

        });

        function onPlay(el) {
            console.log('play');
        }

        function onPause(el) {
         console.log('pause');
        }

    }
```

I get all the iframes in variable 'iframes', it also loops through all and add ready event. But cannot add play and pause events. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The following code would help you with attaching events to your frames.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var x = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
        var nodelist = x.length;
        alert(nodelist);

        for (i = 0; i < nodelist; i++) {

            var player = new Vimeo.Player(x[i]);

            player.on('play', function () {
                console.log('played the video!');
            });

            player.on('ended', function () {
                console.log('ended the video!');
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This works! Only I had to mannually add query properties: api=1 and player_id=videoUniqueId to the frame src url for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually multiple videos play/pause issue as mentioned in my question got solved using froogaloop2.js. I am not writing any extra code for this now as specified by me in question. and my iframe src url does not append api=1 param.